# Running out of memory, fork can't allocate memory

Tags: linux, memory, apache-http-server, php

We are getting out of memory frequently, as well fork cannot allocate memory. I did some investigation.

It seems that scripts are not case as I thought before this. I will share information which I get after analyzing.

I have isolated server, so other people cant reach to server. This will show "true" memory usage in this case.

1. I have no mysqld and apache started [memory usage ~182mb].
2. just started mysqld. no connections made to mysqld [mu ~340mb].
3. httpd started [~360mb].
4. first request to script. [~630mb]. But!! The most interesting part. Memory doesn't get deallocated. Everything looks OK. Script ended, page loaded successfuly. But it still around ~630mb.

Why one request eats 270MB? Why thats not deallocated after request?

**Some stats:**

- Server RAM 512 MB guaranteed
- 256 MB burstable
- PHP memory limit: 256MB

**httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers 1
MinSpareServers 1
MaxSpareServers 3
ServerLimit 50
MaxClients 50
MaxRequestsPerChild  50
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What else is started? ~180MiB RAM after boot into headless system sounds unreasonable. Also, what does that script do? How big is the database backing it up?

Comment: What is exactly "memory usage"? How did you measure it? Is it the one from the first line of `free`?

Comment: Bobby, this is "ps faux" http://pastebin.com/4yKGBTyj

Comment: Cristian, yes, it is from "free" command, also from mediatemple server status, which is the same. 
Also "cat /proc/user_beancounters" http://pastebin.com/H9FZkFWj

Comment: Looks to me like a bulk of it is going to httpd.

Answer (score 0):

> Why one request eats 270MB?

Likely because it accessed a lot of data or metadata in or about files on disk.

> Why thats not deallocated after request?

Because the data might be used again soon. Deallocating it after the request makes the next request expensive. It makes more sense to defer the deallocation until the memory is actually needed for something else.